# Dystopian sci-fi where the ozone layer has been destroyed

Tags: story-identification

I remember the novel being set in a somewhat dystopian near future (relative to the mid 80's!) where destruction of the ozone layer forced people to either stay indoor or wear protective clothing.  There was a middle aged female character who may have been a writer that used a cyber implant located around her vocal cords to dictate to her computer by "subvocalizing" her words.  This was considered a commonly used technology in the context of the novel.  Sadly I don't recall the plot, the title, the author or really ANYTHING that could help me find this story!

Comment: Just a wild guess - Mona Clee's [*Overshoot ?*](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0441005098/ref=kinw_rke_rti_1)

Comment: It looks like this one was published in the late 90's, which would be about a decade later than the timeframe that I remember reading this.  Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 5):

I think that you want David Brin's "Earth".  It's been a while, but I remember everyone but "sun-worshipers" avoiding UV exposure because the ozone layer was destroyed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_%28Brin_novel%29

Comment: AAAAAAH!  Just downloaded this to Kindle - IT'S THE ONE!!!  Thank you SO much!